# Java Parse Multidimensional Array From Post

Tags: java, post, multidimensional-array

Client side I have a form dynamically constructed like so:

```
<form method="post">
    <!-- First set of values in array[0] -->
    <input type="hidden" name="days[0][id]">
    <input type="hidden" name="days[0][name]">
    <input type="hidden" name="days[0][value]">

    <!-- Second set of values in array[0] -->
    <input type="hidden" name="days[0][id]">
    <input type="hidden" name="days[0][name]">
    <input type="hidden" name="days[0][value]">

    <!-- First set of values in array[1] -->
    <input type="hidden" name="days[1][id]">
    <input type="hidden" name="days[1][name]">
    <input type="hidden" name="days[1][value]">

    <!-- In reality I have more sets of data...but for examples sake i'll stop here. -->

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

How can I turn this into a Hashmap server side that represents the organized form data? Only thing I can think of is parsing each request.getParameter() individually, counting the brackets to determine the array depth, adding the values etc. But that seems to leave a lot of room for errors.

Looking for a little guidance on getting started here. Do I need to parse the raw form data, are there method calls that can handle this? I'd prefer not to use a library.

Comment: Using form actions is a relatively old way to do post requests. Using AJAX to pull the data into JSON is the new approach. Then Java has lots of JSON parsers

Comment: Alternatively, this may help. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/Parseaxwwwformurlencodedstring.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good option is to post the data as JSON using [Post Request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) rather than sending the data as individual parameter. If you use it you can directly construct the object too from your request and need to collect only this JSON from request body or get request

Comment: That is my backup plan. Only issue is it requires javascript otherwise the form won't post anything. Which isn't the end of the world but I noticed you can do this sort of thing automatically in PHP and was hoping Java could do something similar...or I could write a custom parser relatively simply.